# How to trigger a lightbox from another page

Tags: jquery, asp.net, lightbox

I have a page where an alert box will be shown as soon as user set from a control panel. To clarify, there is an **#alert** div in Default.aspx page, and user set the data for alert div in Control.aspx. As soon as user submit the data, a fancybox function will be triggered and alert div will show up in Default.aspx. What is the best to follow up to achieve this?

Comment: Are both pages open at the same time?

Comment: Does it differ? There will be a just ajax request and response

Answer (score 0):

hello try to get variable in Default.aspx from Control.aspx

GET variables :

```
Request.QueryString["userSetData"]
```

POST variables :

```
Request.Form["userSetData"]
```

imagine you use GET method you'll have a page like this :

http://domain.com/default.aspx?dataForLightBox=superdata

```
<%
Response.Write "<div id='alert'>getThis " & Request.QueryString("dataForLightBox") & "</div>"
%>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but that's not what i am looking for, imagine that the Default.aspx is like a broadcasting page, always opened and active, i fetch a lot of data via ajax requests without refreshing it, and this alert div is a part of these data which will be user defined and triggered by a button from another page, at least a i believe. I hope it make sense..